# very frequent CPU usage 100% for systemstats

Tags: cpu, macos

I have a MacBook Retina Pro 2013 version with 16GB ram and OS X 10.9.3.

This machine works just fine, except for just one problem; `systemstats` hits 100% CPU usage very frequently, at least 6 times a day.

I've cleaned up the database file for my Spotlight and tried many solutions from Google search results.

What is this `systemstats` and why is it using 100% CPU? I've heard that it indexes something but even so, does it have to use 100% CPU??

Comment: How specifically are you cleaning the database? Wouldn’t that trigger the system to use CPU to regenerate the databases and caches and perhaps even cause it to malfunction or loop?

Comment: Relevant thread on MacRumors forum with additional potentially useful info: https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/major-memory-leak-on-12-2-m1-systemstats.2335199/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

systemstats profiles other processes. The information collected is used, for example, to populate the "Apps Using Significant Energy" section of the battery menu, and the Energy tab in Activity Monitor.
It is actively triggered by clicking on the battery menu, or opening Activity Monitor.
You can find more information on how to disable it in [this article](http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/27/systemstats-cpu-use-slow-mac-os-x/).

Answer (score 2):

Since I found a solution to this problem after suffering from it for a long time I provide my solution here:

**Story:** Apple support told me to restart in safe mode to check if the problem would remain... It didn't. Their solution was to reinstall macOS which would mean a lot of unproductive time... But since the problem didn't appear in safe mode, it must had to do with some startup objects. One of them seems to trigger systemstats so often that it leads to high cpu and memory usage.

**Solution:** So I grabbed the tool EtreCheck (free edition is enough) from the App Store which can list all startup files. I deleted all but those I definitely need... And voila after a restart the problem was gone. :D

There might be a list out there of all folders that contain startup objects... But I found it easer to use this tool. ;)